# cron not even sending local mail to /var/mail/

Tags: cron, email

I'm using a very plain Ubuntu Server 9.04, and cron isn't delivering any mail to my /var/mail/USER (the file hasn't even been created). Here's my full crontab:

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
 15 *  *   *   *     $HOME/.cron/sync-bookmarks.bash
```

If I add

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
 15 *  *   *   *     $HOME/.cron/sync-bookmarks.bash >& /tmp/log
```

then I see the stdout and stderr in /tmp/log. I'm not (yet) interested in actual remote email delivery, just local delivery to the mail spool file. Why isn't mail working? Thanks in advance for any tips.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cron` calls `/usr/sbin/sendmail` to deliver the mail.

Did you install and configure a mail server (sendmail, exim, postfix,  ...)?

--- EDIT ---

For the security aspect, all mail servers can be configured to accept only local mail and to deliver only local mail.

If you need a mail server, probably the easiest option to install `postfix`. The installation process will ask you how you want it configured, and I think one of the options it offers is to handle local mail only.

Comment: No, and I read that it should not be necessary to install a real mail server to have this local mail spool written to. Is this incorrect? I'd rather not install a mail server if possible (security, etc.), but if I have to, what exactly is required? Is just installing sendmail enough?

Comment: @Yang: added info in the response.